# two or more program instances with one DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I'm writing a program on WPF for a workshop. It uses an SQL Server database. Users can add or edit some data in the program (new repairs, owners and repairers). It all  writes to DB. In main Form I have a DataGrid wich shows DB records. DataSource for DataGrid is an ObservableCollection filled from DB.

```
public ObservableCollection<Repair> RepairList { get; set; }
```

and in constructor:

```
RepairList = new ObservableCollection<Repair>(DbContext.Repair.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id));
```

Everything is ok if I run one instance of the program. But what will happen if I launch a second or third instance of the program and put some records in the DB? How can I update values in the DataGrid of other program instances? Will I have any conflicts with records?

Comment: Search for "Transactions" of the DB you're using.

Comment: I would recommend adding a refresh button (and F5 key binding) to allow the user to refresh the data on demand. I would also suggest having the grid be readonly, popping up a separate dialog for editing - that way, you can easily reread the row, with lock.

Comment: @Zastai yup, I decided same

Answer (score 0):

> How can I update values in the DataGrid of other program instances?

The easiest way would be to create a "changed"-timestamp-column for your tables and check periodically, on command or when needed (for example before editing) for rows that were changed since the last check.  When there are changes detected you can reload the ObservableCollection or add/remove Entries to/from it.

> Will I have any conflicts with records?

Yes. When two or more instances edit a row at the same time, only the edits of the last one who saves will remain (if you don't use some advanced logic for merging the edits). A flag-column (like "editLock") could help
There could also be conflicts when inserting with program-generated IDs, so I would recommend auto-generated IDs.

Comment: I thought about timer wich will update collection from DB every 2 seconds. Is it bad practice?

Comment: OMG. . Timer for every 2 seconds!!  that will ruin your app performance. @dantey89

Comment: @dantey89 I agree, updating every 2 seconds - especially without need - is really bad. Most selects on huge tables even take longer! I would **check** if an update is necessary every minute or even after a longer time